# Given an array of objects, link the child objects to their parent based on parentId

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, tree

For example, you have a class:

```
class MyObject {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var parentId: String?
    var children: [MyObject]?
    
    init(name: String, id: String, parentId: String?, children: [MyObject] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.parentId = parentId
        self.children = children
    }
}
```

And an array of that class objects:

```
var objects = [
    MyObject(name: "Parent 1", id: "1", parentId: nil),
    MyObject(name: "Child 1", id: "2", parentId: "1"),
    MyObject(name: "Child 2", id: "3", parentId: "1"),
    MyObject(name: "Parent 2", id: "4", parentId: nil),
    MyObject(name: "Child 3", id: "5", parentId: "4"),
    MyObject(name: "Grandchild 1", id: "6", parentId: "5")
]
```

The result array should be:

```
var objectTree = [
    MyObject(name: "Parent 1", id: "1", parentId: nil, children: [MyObject(name: "Child 1", id: "2", parentId: "1"), MyObject(name: "Child 2", id: "3", parentId: "1"),]),
    MyObject(name: "Parent 2", id: "4", parentId: nil, children: [MyObject(name: "Child 3", id: "5", parentId: "4", children: [MyObject(name: "Grandchild 1", id: "6", parentId: "5")])])
]
```

Consider object with parentId = nil to be the super parent.

I have tried below code and it works, but sometimes it does not maintain the order.

```
let objectsByParentID = Dictionary(grouping: objects, by: \.parentId)

elements.forEach { $0.children = objectsByParentID[$0.id] ?? [] }

let finalObjects = objects.filter { $0.parentId == nil }

finalObjects.forEach { dump($0) }
```

Also, want to check for the alternate solution that works well when the data is large. Not that confident with my solution.

Comment: `Dictionary` does not preserve the order. You basically want to build a [tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-tree-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/) so I would recommend implement it as such. See [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/plus/data-structures/trees) or [this](https://www.kodeco.com/1053-swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure) as example

Comment: Been there, done that: You can 1) create MyObject as an entity in Core Data, 2) create a relationship 1-to-many between MyObject and itself, 3) iterate recursively to get the full tree.

Comment: What is your question exactly, since your end result is an array you can just apply sorting to it to get the order you want. Add `.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })` after the filtering (if you want to sort on name)

Comment: Is there a way you can treat `MyObject` as a node in the entire tree? Meaning, you don't need to maintain parent information in `MyObject`, but only `children`. You will somehow have a reference to the super parent which has an array of children. Each one of those children will only have their own arrays of children and so on. Exactly like how usually a `Tree` data structure is implemented without a reference to the parent.

Comment: When the data is large, `Dictionary` is a good way to do. I don't know there is any reason that you want to maintain the order of children node. You need to provide more about your problem.